# How to remove an object which it doesn't have this object from the array in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
 data =   [{
       "id": "1cUMlLn1pbxHL",
                "assetType": {
                  "id": "1fKBO4w0XHg7H",
                  "code": "M1",
                  "name": "Machine 1"
                }},{
                "id": "ESOSxBjRgmEZ",
                "assetType": {
                  "id": "HIEkQKjpM54V",
                  "code": "M2",
                  "name": "Machine 2"
                }},
              {
                "id": "1og6aPXAAuBo1",
        }]
```

What I'm trying to do here it to remove the object which it has no assetType.

for example the first object and second object has an assetType then the third object doesn't have a assetType then it will remove.

I already tried to use the filter but it return the data undefined.

for example:

```
 [{
       "id": "1cUMlLn1pbxHL",
                "assetType": {
                  "id": "1fKBO4w0XHg7H",
                  "code": "M1",
                  "name": "Machine 1"
                }},{
                "id": "ESOSxBjRgmEZ",
                "assetType": {
                  "id": "HIEkQKjpM54V",
                  "code": "M2",
                  "name": "Machine 2"
                }},
    undefined]
```

instead it should be like this.

```
 [{
           "id": "1cUMlLn1pbxHL",
                    "assetType": {
                      "id": "1fKBO4w0XHg7H",
                      "code": "M1",
                      "name": "Machine 1"
                    }},{
                    "id": "ESOSxBjRgmEZ",
                    "row": 9,
                    "assetType": {
                      "id": "HIEkQKjpM54V",
                      "code": "M2",
                      "name": "Machine 2"
                    }}]
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.filter` cannot add more values to the original array (unless the test predicate function is not pure). It's impossible it could change a particular value to the `undefined`. Please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you should use filter also your object has missing {}

```js
data =[{ "id": "1cUMlLn1pbxHL", "assetType": { "id": "1fKBO4w0XHg7H", "code": "M1", "name": "Machine 1" }},{ "id": "ESOSxBjRgmEZ", "assetType": { "id": "HIEkQKjpM54V", "code": "M2", "name": "Machine 2" }}, { "id": "1og6aPXAAuBo1" }]

             res=data.filter(o=>o.assetType)
             console.log(res)
```